# how to move from one view Controller to another without using a button

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I am using the following code snippet:

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewController") as! secondViewController

self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

I want to execute this code in the viewDidLoad. I will be using something like this in a series of if statements.

I used some code I found here that utilized a label. It did not work. Can a program move from one viewController without using a button? Almost every example, youtube video uses a button. I will be using a button when it is appropriate

Comment: On a side note, it's not always right to move from a view controller to another view controller without the user's concern (explicit user interaction etc.). Because user might think that there's something fishy with your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can not push view controllers before your current view controller loads. You should call your code in your `viewDidAppear`.

If you plan on directing to a particular view when the app launches I suggest you moving your logic to the `AppDelegate` in the method: `didFinishLaunching`. This way you don't need to unnecessarily load views.

Example of a ViewController being pushed in the `viewDidAppear`:

```
///
/// FUNCTION - VIEW DID APPEAR    
///
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

     // GET VIEW CONTROLLER
     let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewController") as! secondViewController

     // PUSH VIEW ONTOP OF CURRENT NAVIGATION CONTROLLER
     self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)

} // END - FUNCTION
```